# Push string if it is not blank with MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am using mogodb aggregate functions, and I want to only push the data if it contains values. I don't want blank values in the resultset

I have written following code

```
{ '$group' => { '_id' => '$user_id',
                'count' => { '$sum' => 1 },
                'row' => {
                  '$push' => {
                    'search_term' => '$search_term'
        }
    }
              }
},
{ '$match' => { '_id' => { '$nin' => ['', nil] } } },
{ '$sort' => { 'count' => -1 } }
```

What changes I need to do in the above code while pushing the search term, remove the blank values

Answer (score 1):

Try using a combination of [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) with [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operators in your **`$group`** pipeline stage. The **`$cond`** operator will add elements to the `row` array using the logic that if `search_term` is not blank then add the field else add the boolean value `false` to the array. You can then filter out the `false` values using [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) in the **`$project`** stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user_id",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "row": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$ne": [ "$search_term", "" ] }, "$search_term", false ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "row": {
                "$setDifference": [ "$row", [false] ]
            },
            "count": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id" : { "$nin": ["", null] } 
        } 
    },
    { 
        "$sort": { "count":  -1 } 
    }
]);
```